# Update SharePoint list item using Java via MS Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, graph-api, java

Can someone offer guidance on why the following code does not update the title field of a SharePoint list item?

```
public void setItemTitle(String siteId, String listId, ListItem item)
{
    ListItem updateItem = new ListItem();
    var  updateRequest = graph.getGraphClient().sites(siteId).lists(listId).items(item.id).fields().buildRequest();

    updateRequest.addHeader("If-Match", item.getRawObject().get("@odata.etag").getAsString());
    updateRequest.addHeader("prefer", "return=representation");

    JsonObject json= new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("Title", "updated title");

    FieldValueSet fieldValueSet =  new FieldValueSet();
    fieldValueSet.setRawObject(null, json);


    FieldValueSet response = updateRequest.patch(fieldValueSet);
}
```

The field does not get updated in the response object, nor in SharePoint.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to get this working:

```
    IFieldValueSetRequest updateRequest = graph.getGraphClient().sites(siteId).lists(listId).items(item.id).fields().buildRequest();
    FieldValueSet fieldValueSet =  new FieldValueSet();
    fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Title", new JsonPrimitive("new Title value"));
    FieldValueSet response = updateRequest.patch(fieldValueSet);
```